# extract digits in a simple way from a python string

Tags: python

I have a string that stores a number and a unit for example

```
x= '$120'
y = ' 90 Degrees F'
banana = '200 kgm'
orange = '300 gm'
total_weight = banana + orange/1000
```

and for example I want to add the weights

```
total_weight  = 200 + 300/1000
```

Thanks!

I'm trying to extract the numbers only to do some operations with these... any idea of what the simplest way to do this? I'm only dealing with these two formats i.e. digits are at the begining or at the end of the string...

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at re module. Regular expressions are meant for extracting structured data from corpus.

Comment: Your own example shows the issue here. banana is in ``kgm`` and orange is in ``gm``, surely that means that the weights are `200000` and `300`, not `200` and `300`, which adds more complexity to the problem. Does that matter to you?.

Comment: He divides `orange` by `1000` for that exact reason

Comment: @jamylak Exactly, is that fixed? Or is that something that could change?

Comment: I presumed that was not part of the question since it was hard-coded in.

Comment: Is it a 200-gram banana, or a 200-kilogram banana?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The simplest way to extract a number from a string is to use regular expressions and `findall`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '300 gm'
>>> re.findall('\d+', s)
['300']
>>> s = '300 gm 200 kgm some more stuff a number: 439843'
>>> re.findall('\d+', s)
['300', '200', '439843']
```

It might be that you need something more complex, but this is a good first step.

Note that you'll still have to call `int` on the result to get a proper numeric type (rather than another string):

```
>>> map(int, re.findall('\d+', s))
[300, 200, 439843]
```

Comment: will this work for float numbers? I'm very new to python world and I have no clue what the d+ stand for.. thanks for you help :)

Comment: You can read up on the different regex expressions [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) but `'\d+'` means one or more digits (the + means one or more).

Comment: @KaRa 'd' stands for 'any decimal digit', and '+' stands for 'match 1 or more repetitions'. For more details have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.

Comment: @KaRa You should learn about regex expressions. Such as `import re re.findall("[a-z]", "abcccd ff")` gets all lowercase letters (a-z) one by one in the string `"abcccd ff"`

Comment: Another approach !!! but only if you have one number in your string !!! will be

int(filter(str.isdigit, ' 90 Degrees F')) 
90 
int(filter(str.isdigit, '$120')) 
120 
int(filter(str.isdigit, '200 kgm')) 
200 
int(filter(str.isdigit, '300 gm')) 300

because (filter(str.isdigit, '300 gm 90')) 
30090

Answer (score 32):

Without using `regex`, you can just do:

```
def get_num(x):
    return int(''.join(ele for ele in x if ele.isdigit()))
```

Result:

```
>>> get_num(x)
120
>>> get_num(y)
90
>>> get_num(banana)
200
>>> get_num(orange)
300
```

**EDIT :**

Answering the follow up question.

If we know that the only period in a given string is the decimal point, extracting a float is quite easy:

```
def get_num(x):
    return float(''.join(ele for ele in x if ele.isdigit() or ele == '.'))
```

Result:

```
>>> get_num('dfgd 45.678fjfjf')
45.678
```

Comment: Awesome! is there anyway to edit this to make also work for float? is it correct to correct to change the return statement to float ?

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple numbers

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression handles floats as well

```
import re
re_float = re.compile(r'\d*\.?\d+')
```

You could also add a group to the expression that catches your weight units.

```
re_banana = re.compile(r'(?P<number>\d*\.?\d+)\s?(?P<uni>[a-zA-Z]+)')
```

You can access the named groups like this `re_banana.match("200 kgm").group('number')`.

I think this should help you getting started.

Comment: This does not handle scientific notation or many other interesting floating point values (e.g. nan, inf)

Comment: banana = '200 kgm'
orange = '300 gm'

banana = int(banana.replace('kgm', '   '))
orange = int (orange.replace('gm', '   '))
print (banana)
print (orange)

total_weight = (banana + (orange/1000 ))
print (total_weight)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x='$120'
>>> import string
>>> a=string.maketrans('','')
>>> ch=a.translate(a, string.digits)
>>> int(x.translate(a, ch))
120
```

Comment: This doesn't work... try it for yourself

Comment: @jaymylak thanks for pointing it.rectified

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing some sort of math with the numbers you might also want to know the units.  Given your input restrictions (that the input string contains unit and value only), this should correctly return both (you'll just need to figure out how to convert units into common units for your math).

```
def unit_value(str):
    m = re.match(r'([^\d]*)(\d*\.?\d+)([^\d]*)', str)
    if m:
        g = m.groups()
        return ' '.join((g[0], g[2])).strip(), float(g[1])
    else:
        return int(str)
```