# Cleanest way to obtain a list of the numeric values in a string

Tags: python, string

What is the cleanest way to obtain a list of the numeric values in a string?

For example:

```
string = 'version_4.11.2-2-1.4'
array  = [4, 11, 2, 2, 1, 4]
```

As you might understand, I need to compare versions.

By "cleanest", I mean as simple / short / readable as possible.

Also, if possible, then I prefer built-in functions over regexp (`import re`).

This is what I've got so far, but I feel that it is rather clumsy:

```
array = [int(n) for n in ''.join(c if c.isdigit() else ' ' for c in string).split()]
```

Strangely enough, I have not been able to find an answer on SO:

- [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4289331/1382251), the input numeric values are assumed to be separated by white spaces
- [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10365225/1382251), the input numeric values are assumed to be separated by white spaces
- [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26825729/1382251), the user only asks for a single numeric value at the beginning of the string
- [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11339210/1382251), the user only asks for a single numeric value of all the digits concatenated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just match on consecutive digits:

```
map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', versionstring))
```

It doesn't matter what's between the digits; `\d+` matches as many digits as can be found in a row. This gives you the desired output in Python 2:

```
>>> import re
>>> versionstring = 'version_4.11.2-2-1.4'
>>> map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', versionstring))
[4, 11, 2, 2, 1, 4]
```

If you are using Python 3, `map()` gives you an iterable `map` object, so either call `list()` on that or use a list comprehension:

```
[int(d) for d in re.findall(r'\d+', versionstring)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Python 2. So I take it (also from all the other answers) that there is not much more which can be achieved with built-in functions, and that `re` is the cleanest solution. Is that correct?

Comment: @barakmanos `re` is part of the standard library, treat it like a built-in. It is the cleanest solution for your specific problem, yes.

Answer (score 5):

I'd solve this with a regular expression, too.

I prefer `re.finditer` over `re.findall` for this task. `re.findall` returns a list, `re.finditer` returns an iterator, so with this solution you won't create a temporary list of strings:

```
>>> [int(x.group()) for x in re.finditer('\d+', string)]
[4, 11, 2, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is definitely the best way to go as @MartijnPieters answer clearly shows, but if you don't want to use it, you probably can't use a list comprehension.  This is how you could do it, though:

```
def getnumbers(string):
    numberlist = []
    substring = ""
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit():
            substring += char
        elif substring:
            numberlist.append(int(substring))
            substring = ""
    if substring:
        numberlist.append(int(substring))
    return numberlist
```

Comment: I think it's not much better than what I already have in my answer. Thanks in any case.

Comment: You need to test for a remainder; you'll miss the last number in a string unless it is followed by non-digits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's a bug I didn't notice, but it's fixed now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are tracking every character and checking if it is a digit, if yes you are adding it to a list, Gets slow for larger strings.

Let's say,

```
  import re
    string='version_4.11.2-2-1.4.9.7.5.43.2.57.9.5.3.46.8.5'
    l=map(int, re.findall('\d+',string))
    print l
```

Hopefully, this should work.
Not sure in the answer above why are we using 'r'.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply resolve this using regular expressions.

```
import re
string = 'version_4.11.2-2-1.4'
p=re.compile(r'\d+')
p.findall(string)
```