# How to search a string in a array list(python-regex)

Tags: python, regex, string, list, pattern-matching

I want to retrieve the value of DP from the following list 'seg'

```
 import re 
 seg = ['AC=2', 'AF=1.00', 'AN=2', 'DB', 'DP=6', 'FS=0.000',
 'MLEAC=2', 'MLEAF=1.00', 'MQ=31.55', 'MQ0=0', 'QD=31.64'] 

 for i in seg:
     name = re.compile(r'DP=(.*)')
     mo = name.search(i)
     if mo:
         print "True",mo
     else:
         print "no"
```

This gives me the output as follows:

```
no
no
no
no
True <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000025DDCD8>
no
no
no
no
no
no
```

The match is found but why is not giving me the DP value? 
Pls help me I am new to regex

Answer (score 1):

`mo` is an object. To get the DP value, use `mo.group(1)` to get the capture group. This will return `6`, and you can parse that using `int`.

Comment: mo.group(0) will return the string "DP=6", so if the goal is to use the value of DP, is it lacking something. We could add this function (found here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365225/extract-digits-in-a-simple-way-from-a-python-string] ) to retrieve the float (or int, see the link)

`DP=mo.group(0)
def get_num(x):

     return float(''.join(ele for ele in x if ele.isdigit() or ele == '.'))


DP = getnum(DP)`

This will return `6.0` for the value of DP. It is less efficient than @nbryans answer though.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. `mo.group(1)` will return 6. No need for finding integers :) I just edited the answer to reflect this. Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

Solution not using regex

```
for i in seg:
    if "DP=" in i:
        x, dp = i.split("=")
        print dp     # You can see we captured the 6
```

`dp` will contain the value you are looking for. You can append this into a list if you want to keep it.

If you want to keep using regex, you should use (as another commenter said) `.group(0)`. You can see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493677/how-do-i-return-a-string-from-a-regex-match-in-python) for more information.

Comment: hello bryans thanks for you answer. Actually I tried this it just gave an error, I am still in the learning phase. Could you please tell me the significance of x, in ur code?

Comment: Hi Angie, in the line `x, dp  = i.split("=")`, we are splitting the string `i` (for example, "DP=6") using `=` as a delimiter. this produces a list as a result, ie `["DP","6"]`

By having `x, dp`, we are having the first entry of that list ("DP") assigned to `x`, and the remainder of the list assigned to `dp`. Since the list is only 2 entries long, `dp` is assigned "6".

What error in particular are you recieving?